# How can I find out which translation unit instantiated the linked function template to debug ODR issues?

Tags: c++, linker, clang, one-definition-rule

In my code I have a function template which tests if certain pointers are convertible, somewhat like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U> bool test() {
    return requires(T* p) { static_cast<U*>(p); };
}
```

Then in X.cpp I have definitions for my classes (included their headers) and call `test<A, B>()`:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
bool foo() {
    return test<A, B>(); // Should return true because static_cast<B*>(<ptr-to-A>) is valid
}
```

and in Y.cpp I only have forward declarations but also call `test<A, B>()`:

```
struct A;
struct B;
bool bar() {
    return test<A, B>(); // Will return false because A and B are unrelated at this point
}
```

The call to `test<A, B>()` in Y.cpp is invalid and breaks my preconditions for `test`, but is legal C++ AFAIK.

If I comile this program (using Clang) with optimizations, `foo()` returns true as expected, but if I compile without optimizations, `foo()` returns false, probably because `test` is not inlined and linked against the version compiled in Y.cpp.

I am aware this is not great design, but unfortunately my entire codebase depends on this.

I would like to know if this is even well-formed C++ or if I perhaps violate ODR here and how I can practically find out which translation unit's version of `test<A, B>` is selected by the linker in `foo` to debug the program. In the real code the calls to `test` are very convoluted and happen deep inside of template instantiations.

I did read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603390/in-which-translation-unit-are-inline-functions-instantiated-and-which-definitio) but the answers only focus on that the standard does not specify it.

Comment: I don't think you can find the translation unit.

Comment: @user12002570 Is there any other way I can practically debug the program?

Comment: Perhaps you could just reject incomplete class types? Or move some function definitions to anonymous namespaces to stop this from being an ODR violation.

Comment: if instantiation of the template fails the error message tells you where it gets instantiated, no?

Comment: *"if this is even well-formed C++..."* Looks like undefined behavior: [Does this downcasting lead to undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505316/does-this-downcasting-lead-to-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Isn't this UB for the reason/dupe mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: @user12002570 I don't think it's UB because of that because I'm not actually performing the cast, I am only testing if the cast would be allowed according to the types.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The instantiation doesn't fail, everything compiles fine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just now added `(void)sizeof(T); (void)sizeof(U);` to `test` and I get tons of compilation errors so this seems promising

Comment: yes, but if you do make it fail, there will be an error message

Comment: I believe this is an ODR violation, but I'm not 100% sure.  As a template, `test` is implicitly `inline`, which means it can be defined in multiple translation units if and only if all of the definitions are the same.  Since the definition of `test<A, B>` in X.cpp is not the same as in Y.cpp (since `A` and `B` are incomplete in Y.cpp) your program violates the ODR.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Yes, this statement on the [cppreference ODR page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) seems to suggest that as well: _For a class, a definition is required wherever the class is used in a way that requires it to be complete._

Answer (score 2):

I admit I don't completely understand your issue, and not sure if the following helps. Though, to find out where the template is instantiated you can make instantiation fail (but make sure it fails only on instantiation not earlier already).

```
template <typename T, typename U> bool test() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T,struct foo>);
    return requires(T* p) { static_cast<U*>(p); };
}

int main()
{
    test<int,int>();     // <- required from here
}
```

[Resulting error message](https://godbolt.org/z/e6vYr7h3P) reports the point of instantiation via `required from here`:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'bool test() [with T = int; U = int]':
<source>:10:18:   required from here
<source>:4:24: error: static assertion failed
    4 |     static_assert(std::is_same_v<T,struct foo>);
      |                   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:4:24: note: 'std::is_same_v<int, test<int, int>()::foo>' evaluates to false
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe I did not explain well enough, I probably have a hundred calls to `test` like the one in X.cpp that are valid (with types `A` and `B`) and one like in Y.cpp that is invalid, so this would still be searching the needle in the haystack. But it seems the suggestion by @holyblackcat to test for completeness by `sizeof(T), sizeof(U)` solves my issue :)

Comment: @chrysante maybe I didnt read well enough ;). This only addresses the question in the title actually